# the '.htaccess' file won't work on my apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, windows-7

I have an Apache server installed on my windows machine using XAMPP. Now I'm trying to use a premade .htaccess file for one of my projects, but it doesn't seem to be seeing it. The project just totally ignores it, even though I've enabled mod_rewrite.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this? I can't fix it if it just doesn't work and doesn't show me any errors.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your httpd.conf file, you must enable .htaccess overriding with [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for the directory where the .htaccess file is (or parent thereof). If it is set to 'None', the .htaccess files will be ignored.